# How to upload images into MySQL database using PHP code

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image-uploading

I am trying to save images in my database from HTML form. I have written PHP code to accomplish this task. The program is not generating any error message, but also not inserting image data in MySQL database. Kindly check it.
Here i am sharing a excerpt from my code.

```
        /*-------------------
    IMAGE QUERY 
    ---------------*/


    $file   =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    if(!isset($file))
    {
      echo 'Please select an Image';
    }
    else 
    {
       $image_check = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
       if($image_check==false)
       {
        echo 'Not a Valid Image';
       }
       else
       {
        $image = file_get_contents ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        if ($image_query = mysql_query ("insert into product_images values (1,'$image_name',$image )"))
        {
          echo $current_id;
         //echo 'Successfull';
        }
        else
        {
          echo mysql_error();
        }
       }
   }
        /*-----------------
    IMAGE QUERY END
    ---------------------*/

    <form action='insert_product.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' ></br>
            File        : <input type='file' name= 'image' >
    </form>
```

> Error Message
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Comment: You can store in your database base64 of the image, or it's path on server.

Comment: Don't save images into db, unless it's a core part of your application.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Firstly, you should check if your **image column is BLOB type**!

I don't know anything about your SQL table, but if I'll try to make my own as an example.

We got fields *`id`* (int), *`image`* (blob) and *`image_name`* (varchar(64)).

So the code should look like this (assume ID is always '1' and let's use this mysql_query):

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `product_images` (`id`, `image`, `image_name`) VALUES ('1', '{$image}', '{$image_name}')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // Error handling
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
}
```

You are doing it wrong in many ways. Don't use mysql functions - they are deprecated! Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). You should also think about storing files locations on disk. Using MySQL for storing images is thought to be Bad Idea™. Handling SQL table with big data like images can be problematic.

Also your HTML form is out of standards. It should look like this:

```
<form action="insert_product.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File: </label><input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

Sidenote:

When dealing with files and storing them as a BLOB, the data must be escaped using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), otherwise it will result in a syntax error.

Comment: its not working.Undefined variable: _FILE and  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty is showing

Comment: @SANDEEP: I fixed that.

Comment: To be safe from SQL Injection I would use mysqli_real_escape_string or equivalent instead of addslashes. Best way to do this would use PDO prepared statements.

Comment: I came about this Q&A from another question asked today. When dealing with files and storing as `BLOB`, the data **must** be escaped using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, otherwise it **will** result in a syntax error. This not just "to be safe", it's because it must be done.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - you can edit my post to contain that fix. It worked as it is the time when I was answering this question.

Answer (score 23):

**Just few more details**：

- Add mysql field

`` `image` blob ``

- Get data from image

`$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));`

- Insert image data into db

`` $sql = "INSERT INTO `product_images` (`id`, `image`) VALUES ('1', '{$image}')"; ``

- Show image to the web

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'">`

- End

Comment: it should be $_FILES *

Comment: should be longblob or mediumblob. 'blob' stores just 64k of information. I learned that by having half my images cut off

Answer (score -2):

This is the perfect code for uploading and displaying image through MySQL database.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
     if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE)
     {
        echo " error ";
     }
     else
     {
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
        saveimage($image);
     }
    }
    function saveimage($image)
    {
        $dbcon=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dbname');
        $qry="insert into tablename (name) values ('$image')";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$qry);
        if($result)
        {
            echo " <br/>Image uploaded.";
            header('location:urlofpage.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo " error ";
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```