# Article thumbnail with php

Tags: php, mysql

after much attempts i failed to implement a principal image for the article using an image upload and mysql.

In the admin page I have a form with tinymce textarea for the article and an image upload for the principal article image.

I need to upload the image into the database with the text of tinymce, and display it in the index.

I am grateful to who can help me.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, and outline the ***exact*** problem - PHP for the style? (What?) or uploading the image, or is it storing the image and retrieving it?

Comment: I need help for the php part. UPLOAD | STORING IN THE DATABASE | VIEW IT IN INDEX.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? Then we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: No, i've search a help in internet but i dont'find anything. In some article talk only of wordpress -.-

Comment: Show us what you have tried, nobody is going to do ALL the work for you

Comment: I asked for help, I did not need the code, but tutorials for help me.
@LemuelBotha i have solved with the answer of 'Harry'. Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it seems you're wanting a tutorial on how to;

- Upload an image to your server
- Store the image in a MySQL database
- Retrieve the image from MySQL

#### Some useful resources;

- [about.com](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/Upload_file_sql.htm)
- [A useful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17718807/3000179)

#### Some Notes

- Please use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) not not vanilla [mysql_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) to write/read from your MySQL database, due to insecurities and it being deprecated.

  - The [about.com](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/Upload_file_sql.htm) link uses [mysql_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), so it's probably not a "useful" resource, but it will give you the concept.
- Don't ask SO to code for you - we will fix things for you, and point out where you're going wrong