# How to insert photo into MySQL database/ using PHP?

Tags: php

Good day...
I have to insert a photo into MySQL database,,,,
But this message appears

> Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp\www\great\index.php on line 41

Line 41:

> ```
>                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['fileToUpload'], "int"));
> ```

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<?php require_once('Connections/greatCONN.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO great (id) VALUES (%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['fileToUpload'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_greatCONN, $greatCONN);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $greatCONN) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="form" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIKYX.jpg)

I'll be very thankful for helping me :)

Comment: Is `fileToUpload` the name of file browse input? Also please add more code.

Comment: If `fileToUpload` is actually a file, then it would be in `$_FILES['fileToUpload']` and not `$_POST['fileToUpload']`

Comment: Yes @AnkiiG fileToUpload  is the field of photo in MySQL database

Comment: Don't edit with photos of your code. Post the actual code.

Comment: Also, your code photos don't even include `GetSQLValueString($_POST['fileToUpload'], "int"));`, and all references to `fileToUpload` in those photos are `$_FILES['fileToUpload']`. So why do you  have `$_POST['fileToUpload']`?

Comment: @Sean I've posted the whole codes, for ur kind review and help

Comment: Can you show your table schema? what is the data type of the column

Comment: @AhmedKhan I've edited my question just right now,,, and insert my table's screenshot

Comment: Data type should be blob for image upload and second there is an issue in your insert query it should be
`"INSERT INTO great (fileToUpload) VALUES (%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['fileToUpload'], "int")`

Comment: @AhmedKhan I've tried it,, and this message shown: 
Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp\www\great\index.php on line 40
Column 'fileToUpload' cannot be null................Line 40:  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO great (fileToUpload) VALUES (%s)", GetSQLValueString($_POST['fileToUpload'], "int"));
!!!

Comment: try this
`sprintf("INSERT INTO great (id) VALUES (".GetSQLValueString($_POST['fileToUpload'], "int").")");`

Comment: also I refer you to look at this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717506/how-to-upload-images-into-mysql-database-using-php-code

Comment: I'm so sorry for disturbing u @AhmedKhan :) please forgive me ,,,,,, tried it,still n't working :( ......................... error msg said:Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp\www\great\index.php on line 40................Line 40: $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO great (id) VALUES (".GetSQLValueString($_POST['fileToUpload'], "int").")");

Comment: change your POST to FILE

Comment: Changed it to FILES @AhmedKhan ..........Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\great\index.php on line 10 ,,,,,,,,, Line 10:  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

Comment: Yes this will give error because the value of File is not a string. remove this mysql_escape_string(

Comment: removed it @AhmedKhan ,,,,,server run this msg: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: are you inserting your primary key too!

Comment: Yess @AhmedKhan I've already insert ID as PRIMARY key

Comment: that's why it is giving error! You have already made your primary key auto increment so you don't need to add it every time when you insert data

Comment: done @AhmedKhan ,,,,,,,,,but I don't know how to avoid this msg:((  Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp\www\great\index.php on line 40
Column 'fileToUpload' cannot be null )) .....Line 40:   $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO great (fileToUpload) VALUES (%s)", GetSQLValueString($_POST['fileToUpload'], "int"));

Comment: use this link to know how to upload image on database
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717506/how-to-upload-images-into-mysql-database-using-php-code

Comment: thanks alot @AhmedKhan for ur cooporation,,,,,,,,,,,,,,one more question pls/ how to make the photo stored in my database be shown in my application form?

Comment: Try to google that out

Comment: I will ^__^ thank u very much @AhmedKhan

Answer (score 0):

Choose datatype varchar instead of integer to upload photo.

Answer (score 0):

There should be $_FILES['fileToUpload'] if it is any file

Comment: my file is (uploads),,,,,,,,(fileToUpload) is photos field in my database

Comment: if the file is uploaded, it will be in $_FILES[nameOfFileUploadHtmlInput] <-- not the field in your database, but the html input that is used to upload the file. To verify, var_dump($_FILES) and see what the indexes are.  The error is telling you $_POST['fileToUpload'] does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_FILES['fileToUpload']` instead of `$_POST['fileToUpload']`