# Can't display image from MySQL database in PHP only show ��n�ind���g�����Y�

Tags: php, mysql

I try to display the image from database but only show ��n�ind���g�����Y����... I don't know which part got problem. Please help me. Every help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

**timetable.php**

```
include("include/config.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM time_table";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row["t_image"]; ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo $row["t_name"]; echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

    $link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","course_registration_system");

?>
```

My database:
**time_table**

```
t_id   t_name                t_image 
1     Use Case Diagram.jpg   [BLOB - 64 KiB]
```

Comment: check this => [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17718807/5208282)

Comment: You're outputting the image binary straight to HTML? That won't work. You could do it with data URL if you really need to have it inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, `<img />` tag must have the URL of the image. Reading your question, I suppose that `<?php echo $row["t_image"]; ?>` outputs the complete image, not only it's URL.

In that case you have two options:

1. Build a URL that points to another script which ouputs the image
2. Output the image in base64, so it's embedded in the HTML.

Maybe this second option is the simplest:

```
<?php echo "<td>";?> 
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row["t_image"]); ?>" 
     height="100" 
     width="100" />
```

Of course, if your image is not a PNG but a JPG, change the mimetype ccordingly,

Comment: Thanks! Btw how to display all the image from database?

Comment: Excuseme, I don't understand your question...

Comment: For example, I have 3 images in the database and I have tried the code you are teaching is only show the first image...how do I display all three images?

Comment: My code only replaces a line of your code. Yu must put it inside your `while` block

Comment: Thank you for helping me to solve the problem