# how to insert an image into an sql query

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a side project, and practicing my SQL queries. My question is how do I insert an image file into this query I have? Never had to or been shown how to do it before.

```
INSERT INTO products (prod_category,prod_title,image,conditions,in_stock,price,description) VALUES ("gaming tower",   ,"used","yes",500,"new gaming tower");
```

Just to add, I'm just curious to the method, and using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Either as a `BLOB` or store it locally then save the file path

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717506/how-to-upload-images-into-mysql-database-using-php-code)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a best practice to store images in database. It's heavy, increases needed space, is not practical because you need to parse it for displaying.

More simple is the following approach:

- Upload your file (you've already)
- Store your file on disk
- Store the path to file in your database
- Display your image with basic html `<img src="">`. The `src` attribute can be filled with the stored path from your database