# How to upload/download image into/from mysql db through httpp by means of DefaultHttpClient

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to save and load pictures to/from MySQL database on the server in my Java Android code through http. Till now I used DefaultHttpClient class to communicate with http server using PHP on server side.
Is there any way to do what I want with DefaultHttpClient and PHP? Also I would appreciate another solution not using DefaultHttpClient but using PHP.
I'd appreciate some code samples.

Comment: Picasso , glide etc , google them

Comment: Do this libraries allow download and upload pics from/to server? Is it better to store in DB filenames only instead of using BLOB field.

Comment: not upload only download , for upload use some networking lib like volley , httpURLconnection,retrofit and many more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload images into MySQL database using PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717506/how-to-upload-images-into-mysql-database-using-php-code)