# React native image upload to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, react-native

How to upload an image from React Native into MySQL using PHP?
I have used the React Native image picker to choose the image but how can I upload it to MySQL using PHP?

Comment: does that answer help you ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question consists of **two parts**:

---

### Part one: (client-side)

For the mobile part (React native):

You could use [this library](https://github.com/malsapp/react-native-photo-upload)

OR following this article that mentions a step-by-step image uploading:

[Uploading Images From React Native To Your Server](https://www.20spokes.com/blog/uploading-images-from-react-native-to-your-server)

---

Now it comes to the second part:

### Part two: (server-side)

You should allow your php code to receive images from the form data submitted

You could follow the following helpful article : [Upload Image to Database and Server using HTML,PHP and MySQL](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/upload%20image%20to%20database%20and%20server%20using%20HTML,PHP%20and%20MySQL.php)

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717506/how-to-upload-images-into-mysql-database-using-php-code) is wonderful too.